# How to use a function's output as another function's input?

Tags: php, function, validation, user-input, filter-var

I have this function to check the formal correctness of the user's email in a webform, in order to send an email to the webmaster using the user's email address.

```
<?php
function verificarEmails($rte) {
    $_POST['emailRemitente'] = $rte;
    if (!filter_var($rte, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>Oops! el mail debe ser correcto";
    } else { 
        return $rte;
    }
}
```

If I want to use the output of that function within a second function (the one that actually sends the email), should I add (inside the second function), something like this?

```
$emailRemitente = verificarEmails($_POST['emailRemitente']);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm very sure there's this big fat elephant that I'm missing. This `$_POST['emailRemitente']` is the user input, and the problem is that the `verificarEmails()` function won't work (it allows malformed emails to be sent using the form).

### Update:

The second function complete is this:

```
<?php
function enviarMails($correo) {
    $miEncabezado = "Estimada,<br>";
    $emailRemitente = verificarEmails($_POST['emailRemitente']);
    $nombreRemitente = $_POST['nombreRemitente'];
    $para   = $correo;
    $asunto = 'Urgente';
    $mensaje = $miEncabezado . $GLOBALS['texto'];
    $headers = 'From: '.$nombreRemitente.' '.'<'.$emailRemitente.'>'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    //mando mail a los usuarios
    $envioUsuarios = mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers);
    if($envioUsuarios) {
        echo '<br><span class="ok">Mensaje enviado a '.$correo.'</span><br>';
    } else {echo'<br><span class="error">No se mandó mail a '.$correo.'</span><br>';}
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You don't need this line: `$_POST['emailRemitente'] = $rte;`

Comment: There are two options. Option 1) You return the email (if it is valid) or false otherwise and then you need to check if the returned value is false. If so, print message and exit (or something else). Option 2) What you already do, but halt program with `exit;` after printing error message.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: I've updated the post with the second function, sorry for not posting it the first time.

Comment: @Maverick, thans for your comment, but even without $_POST['emailRemitente'] = $rte; it doesn't work...

Comment: where do you put your verificarEmails() function.

Comment: Just before the second function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

function enviarMails($correo) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['emailRemitente'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $miEncabezado = "Estimada,<br>";
        $nombreRemitente = $_POST['nombreRemitente'];
        $para   = $correo;
        $asunto = 'Urgente';
        $mensaje = $miEncabezado . $GLOBALS['texto'];
        $headers = 'From: '.$nombreRemitente.' '.'<'.$_POST['emailRemitente'].'>'."\r\n";
        $headers. = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers. = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        //mando mail a los usuarios
        if(mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers)) { 
            echo '<br><span class="ok">Mensaje enviado a '.$correo.'</span><br>'; 
        } else {
            echo'<br><span class="error">No se mandó mail a '.$correo.'</span><br>';
        }
    } else {
        // email not validated
    }
}
```

With **2 functions**:

```
<?php

function verificarEmails($rte) {
    if (!filter_var($rte, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}

function enviarMails($correo) {
    if (verificarEmails($_POST['emailRemitente']) {
        $miEncabezado = "Estimada,<br>";
        $nombreRemitente = $_POST['nombreRemitente'];
        $para   = $correo;
        $asunto = 'Urgente';
        $mensaje = $miEncabezado . $GLOBALS['texto'];
        $headers = 'From: '.$nombreRemitente.' '.'<'.$_POST['emailRemitente'].'>'."\r\n";
        $headers. = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers. = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        //mando mail a los usuarios
        if(mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers)) { 
            echo '<br><span class="ok">Mensaje enviado a '.$correo.'</span><br>'; 
        } else {
            echo'<br><span class="error">No se mandó mail a '.$correo.'</span><br>';
        }
    } else {
        // email not validated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!! It does work that way, but I couldn't understand why it didn't worked when trying to separate the two functions...

Answer (score 1):

```
function verificarEmails($rte) {
    //$_POST['emailRemitente'] = $rte;
    if (!filter_var($rte, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>Oops! el mail debe ser correcto";
    } else { 
        return $rte;
    }
}
//another function
function func2($value2) {
     return verificarEmails($value2);

}

echo func2('jack@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! 
What I don't quite understand is why doesn't work with verificarEmails($_POST['emailRemitente'])...

Comment: it should work your code should run but i surprise it's not working.
some time may be cache problem.